# Текст социальной рекламы: соответствует ли нормативным и коммуникативным требованиям русской речи?

Tags: грамотная-речь, коммуникативные-требования

"Любовь и верность защищают, если мы оба сделали тест на ВИЧ".

Comment: По-моему, корректно так: "Любовь и верность **защитят**, если мы оба сделали тест на ВИЧ". Почему? — оставляю этот вопрос знатокам. А еще лучше так: "Любовь и верность защищают те пары, которые сделали тест на ВИЧ".

Comment: "Любовь и верность защитят, если **вы** оба сделали тест на ВИЧ". Мы-то знаем, знаем, сделали тест или нет, зачем нам *если*? А еще лучше так: "Любовь и верность защищают те пары, которые сделали тест на ВИЧ". – М

Comment: Честно говоря, в любой формулировке такие лозунги отдают пошлостью. Уж лучше с юмором, как-нибудь так: "Пройдите вместе тест на ВИЧ и спите спокойно"

Answer (score 1):

**"Любовь и верность защитят нас, если мы оба сделаем тест на ВИЧ".**
Потому что:
а) если это реклама - она должна побуждать сделать что-те, еще не сделанное, а не описывать то, что уже сделано;
б) должна быть четкая причинно-следственная связь: любовь и верность уже не спасут, если один из партнеров заражен ранее;
в) в то же время необходимо дать понять, что если вы оба сделаете тест и убедитесь, что изначально все в порядке, то в дальнейшем любовь и верность смогут это сберечь.
Общий посыл фразы должен четко указывать на концепцию "прежде чем думать о том, каким образом сохранить что-то в дальнейшем, убедитесь в том, что вы это еще не потеряли".

Answer (score 0):

Предложенный текст не соответствует ничему: ни смыслу, ни грамматике.

В качестве варианта:

**Доверие  больше, а любовь крепче, если мы оба сдали тест на ВИЧ.**

Пояснение.

Тест на ВИЧ увеличивает доверие, но к верности не имеет прямого отношения. А вот доверие действительно защищает любовь

Comment: По-моему, скрытый смысл рекламы таков: сначала оба проверьтесь, а потом  не спите с другими - и будете уверены, что вы не заболеете. ("Защитят" — от СПИДА)

Comment: Ну тогда так: Наша любовь и верность под защитой, если мы оба сдали тест на ВИЧ.

Comment: Верность (отсутствие измен) и есть защита. Так я понимаю.

Comment: Как-то так: Верность защитит вашу любовь, если вы оба сдали тест на ВИЧ

Comment: Как я уже писал, про "нас" малоуместно "если", лучше про "вас"

Comment: Надо всё-таки выразиться конкретно и ясно, без скрытых намеков, а то не все поймут: Верность и постоянное партнерство защитят ваше здоровье и любовь, если вы оба сдали тест на ВИЧ.